# How to add multiple textBox values in a text file (.txt) in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have used this code, but it is only saving the value for the `textBox1`. The other two values are not saving. Please check the  input and output scenario.

**Input:**

```
Name: aaa
College: bbb
Roll: 111
```

**Output:**

```
Name: aaa
College:
Roll:
```

---

```
string[] contents = new string[3];

contents[0] = "Name: " + textBox1.Text;
contents[1] = "College: " + textBox2.Text;
contents[2] = "Roll: " + textBox3.Text;

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\...\test.txt", contents, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works as expected. Your code is correct. There are two reasons you see problems:

1. Your textboxes are blank.
2. You are looking at incorrect file.

Try to print values to debug console, maybe other textboxes are indeed blank.

```
string[] contents = new string[3];        
contents[0] = $"Name: {textBox1.Text}";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"text1: {textBox1.Text}");
contents[1] = $"College: {textBox2.Text}";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"text2: {textBox2.Text}");
contents[2] = $"Roll: {textBox3.Text}";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"text3: {textBox3.Text}");
```

Comment: Still, it's not working. I am not able to understand why.

Comment: post your sample which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Just a form with textBoxes and a button to save the values in a local text file.

Comment: My sample works fine and it's the same as you described. Post your sample.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting you. The one I have added in the question and the one u have done. I tried both, none is working for me.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without sample. Your code works fine. Post your sample to github and give a link to it.

Comment: Ohh, Okay... I will do that later today. I will inform you then. Thank you so much.

Comment: Solved it. It was a silly mistake. Thank you for the help.